# How do I modify a collection after being calculated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, collections, lambda

I have a method that performs some reporting, something like this:

```
 var views = people.Viewers
            .GroupBy(v => new { v.Viewer.Country, v.Viewer.Gender })
            .Select(v =>
                new StatisticViewModel
                {
                    Country = v.Key.Country,
                    Females = v.Count(r => r.Viewer.Gender.Equals(false)),
                    Males = v.Count(r => r.Viewer.Gender.Equals(true)),
                    TotalViewsForCountry = v.Count()
                    //I will calculate this bad guy after I have all the info:
                    //PercentageOfViews = xxxxx
                });
```

Now I have a collection of views, however I have one more property to calculate, that is the percentage of views for that country, this is where my problem is, I've tried many things, like:

```
//Total number of Views
var totalViews = views.Sum(v=>v.TotalViewsForCountry);

//When I return this to my view the property is 0!
views.Each(v=>v.PercentageOfViews = v.TotalViewsForCountry / totalViews * 100);
```

I tried `ToList` on the `Collection`, `foreach`, `forloop`... Everything.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

This is the View Model

```
 public class StatisticViewModel
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int Females { get; set;}
    public int Males { get; set; }
    public int TotalViewsForCountry { get; set; }
    public double PercentageOfViews { get; set; }
 }
```

**Solution:**

My problem was that I was using Each (automapper extension - by error) instead of ToList  the collection and then using ForEach, now my field are being populated correctly.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: @NicoSchertler each is a linq function, System.Linq to perform an action over each element of the collection. See the update for the ViewModel.

Comment: No, it's *not* a LINQ function.  LINQ *specifically* is designed for querying, not for mutating collections or causing side effects.

Comment: You are absolutely right, this was an Automapper extension method over collection. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing integer division when you intended to be performing floating point division.  Your count, divided by `totalViews` and then truncated to an int will be equal to `0`.

Cast one of the relevant numbers to a `double` first:

```
views.Each(v=>v.PercentageOfViews = v.TotalViewsForCountry / (double)totalViews * 100);
```

Comment: I chose this since you detected the Each instead of ForEach in a way. Thanks to Henrik too for pointing in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is integer division. Change

```
v.TotalViewsForCountry / totalViews * 100
```

to

```
100.0 * v.TotalViewsForCountry / totalViews
```